# Magento 1.9 redirect on checkout/cart after online payment

Tags: checkout, checkoutsession

I've applied the latest security patches from the Magento website and after that, I have strange behaviour:

After an order is done with online payment (card) is redirecting to **checkout/cart** via **public function successAction()** from **app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php**

This means that after the page is redirected to the payment website and then is back to our website, is loosing somehow session.

**$session->getLastSuccessQuoteId()** is returning NULL and because of that is doing this.

I've even check

```
$lastQuoteId = $session->getLastQuoteId();

$lastOrderId = $session->getLastOrderId();

$lastRecurringProfiles = $session->getLastRecurringProfileIds();
```

and those are null also. I've also looked to the DB and the quote is there and everything seems to be ok.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

We have the exact same issue on Magento 1.9 ... We have a custom payment module.

Some (not ALL) customers doesn't see success page because $session->getLastSuccessQuoteId() is returning NULL. They also don't get an order email.

It seems that something is wrong with sessions ...

Did you find any solutions to this issue?

Comment: did you find a solution to this issue?